# Strings not being read correctly from file using fscanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm using `fscanf` to take input of a specific format. The line I'm trying to read is:

> A B C D E F G H I J K x

My `fscanf` code looks like:

```
fscanf(circuit, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %c ",
       str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9, str10, str11, &a);
```

In this example "circuit" is the name of the file. For some reason, `"K"` and `'x'` get read correctly (as `str11` and `a` respectively), but the rest of the characters do not get read correctly. The reason I've opted for the string identifier vs the char identifier is because the line may potentially contain single digit integers. In the case of an integer I just convert the string to an integer in a later code block. Why isn't this working correctly?

Comment: Can you just remove the spaces between all %s and try again?

Comment: are `str1, str2` etc. all pointing to the same buffer?

Comment: the problem seems to be the char array, try str1[2]

Comment: It's hard telling what could the problem without seeing rest of your program. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You really, really need to show the definitions of the strings.  For example, if you have `char str1[1];` etc, you will run into problems.  The trailing blank in the format string is dangerous.  It will read all the white space (blanks, tabs, newlines — especially newlines!) up to the next non-white space character (which will be left behind in the input for further processing), or EOF.  If this data is coming from a file, it is not too bad, usually.  If the data is coming from a terminal, this is excruciatingly awful.  It also often wreaks havoc if the input is from a pipe or socket.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code working on my machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main()
{
    char str1[2], str2[2], str3[2], str4[2], str5[2], str6[2], str7[2], str8[2], str9[2], str10[2], str11[2];
    char a;
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
    fputs("A B C D E F G H I J K x", fp);

    rewind(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %c ", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9, str10, str11, &a);

    printf("Read String1 |%s|\n", str1);
    printf("Read String2 |%s|\n", str2);
    printf("Read String3 |%s|\n", str3);
    printf("Read Character |%c|\n", a);

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Output :

```
Read String1 |A|
Read String2 |B|
Read String3 |C|
Read Character |x|
```

Comment: This has most likely nothing to do with the actual question. The OP has not provided context and you just took a wild guess at a correct implementation. There is also no satisfactory explaination.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Confiz-3C.  When you want to post code or program output, lay it out in the text edit box as you want it to appear.  Avoid tabs; usually use 4 spaces of indent, though the amount isn't critical.  Then select all the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it, like sebastianbrosch did for you.  That makes it appear like code.

Comment: Note that it's good practice to test that the `fopen()` succeeded before using `fp`. It's also be good practice to check that `fscanf()` returns the correct value (12); if it doesn't, something has gone horribly wrong. Especially with `char str1[2];`, it would be good to protect the code from overflows with `%1s`. These are all refinements that would improve the code. I think you've made a reasonable inference about what the code in the question should look like — but because we have only the `fscanf()` statement and not the rest, it is only inference. It may help Sara; it may not.

Comment: See also my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951258/strings-not-being-read-correctly-from-file-using-fscanf/33951719#comment55662712_33951258) about trailing blanks in the format string — it's bad news and should be avoided.